# Creating an Objective C class UIViewController in latest xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I've just upgraded my xcode to the latest version after having a small few month break from development.

I'm trying to create an Objective-C class UIViewController in my empty application, but I've noticed that I now have to select from 4 different file types (Empty File, Category, Protocol and Extension). My question is what would be the appropriate file type? I'm after .h, .m and .xib UIViewControllers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select "Cocoa Touch Class"

[image]

You then enter what type of class it is, in your case `UIViewController` the class name you want, and the language.

[image]

Comment: Legend. Thank you very much.